# Ansible :execute playbook from localhost through bastion host

Tags: ansible

I am newbie to the ansible

We are doing our deployments via ansible and a bastion host is provisioned for the deployments.

The current approach I am using is to clone the ansible repo in bastion host and run the commands from that folder

My question is it possible to run the ansible code through the local machine through bastion??

(basically, avoid the repo in bastion host)

Comment: yes you can, you can use ssh agent setup or ssh forwarding

Comment: Can you explain a little bit

Comment: from your host, in your project ansible, you can use  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p bastion.test.com

Comment: So ansible should be installed in the bastion host??

Comment: not in this use case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you want to provision a couple of VMs `172.20.0.10` and `172.20.0.11` in your development environment going through your `172.20.0.1` bastion. Your inventory looks a bit like this

```
[development]
172.20.0.10
172.20.0.11
```

Then you can edit your `~/.ssh/config` and add

```
Host bastion
    Hostname 172.20.0.1
    User youruser

Host 172.20.*
    ProxyJump bastion
    User youruser
```

Then you can test a `ssh 172.20.0.10` that should land you in your first VM. If it works for SSH, Ansible should work the same.

Note, you can run ansible with `-vvv` (or is it one more `v`, not sure atm), you'll see the SSH commands Ansible is running.

Note 2, ProxyJump requires a recent OpenSSH, 6.7 at least if I remember correctly

Comment: Yes, ProxyJump is just a modern shortcut to the most common case of ProxyCommand. But I don't have an example at hand for this one. On the command line though, `ssh -J Jumphost FooServer` is equivalent to `ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p Jumphost" FooServer` (`-J` behing ProxyJump's CLI option)

Comment: Yep, that's it: `ProxyJump bastion` is equivalent to `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p bastion` in `~/.ssh/config`.
If you want more information about how to run ansible with a bastion, this blogpost is very helpful : https://blog.scottlowe.org/2015/12/24/running-ansible-through-ssh-bastion-host/

Comment: this solution working only in local machine ... you have to replicate ssh configuration (~/.ssh/config) to another machine to run ansible...better solution is configure jump o proxy command directly in ansible.conf

Answer (score 4):

### Using this data

```
host remoto : 10.0.1.121
user remoto : application_user
ssh key : app_ssh_key

host bastian : 212.34.345.12
user bastian : bastian_user
ssh key: bastian_ssh_key
```

and using key to access with ssh (you have to store keys in a secure storage, not with ansible playbook).

### In a ssh single command

```
$ ssh application_user@10.0.1.121 -i path/to/app_ssh_key \
  -o ProxyCommand="ssh -q bastian_user@212.34.345.12 -i path/to/bastian_ssh_key -W %h:%p"
```

### In ansible

you can use two method:

#### Method 1

Use variables for inventory machine/group, in order to have different connection option for different machine/group.

Add to inventory file:

```
[remote-vm]
10.0.1.121

[remote-vm:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=application_user
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=path/to/app_ssh_key
ansible_ssh_common_args= -o ProxyCommand="ssh -q bastian_user@212.34.345.12 -i path/to/bastian_ssh_key -W %h:%p"
```

#### Method 2

Single configuration valid for all inventory machines.

Add to/replace in `ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
remote_user = application_user

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args=-i path/to/app_ssh_key -o ProxyCommand="ssh -q bastian_user@212.34.345.12 -i path/to/bastian_ssh_key -W %h:%p"
```